# SharePoint 365 - Subsite versus App

Tags: sharepoint-addin, office-365

I think I have read the entire Internet but can't seem to grasp this ...

I am building a custom solution using SharePoint 365 and Project Online with CSOM. This is the first time I have dealt with the Office 365 side of SharePoint but on-premises is just not an option in this case.

We created a subsite in the main online Site Collection that will house this solution -- let's call it ProjectIntake. Inside this subsite I want to house all of the custom lists and libraries that will serve as the datastore for my project and I want to create a custom front-end that will use CSOM or REST to CRUD these lists and libraries.

I can't seem to find out how to edit the Home.aspx for that subsite in NAPA so I figured I would create an app that would house the "front-end" of my solution.

Is there a way to automatically forward the Home.aspx of this new subsite to my app's Default.aspx page? The reason this is important is because the app's URL is not something we want to send out to the team and certainly don't expect them to remember a URL like that. The link to the subsite is simple and that's where we want everyone to go to do their work.

So, can I forward to an app or is there a way to build this solution directly on that new subsite? I've read a whole book on NAPA solutions and spents hours researching the new 2013 APP model but I still don't get this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom front-end would be an App. Include in that app a Client Web Part (AppPart).

On the home page, insert that AppPart and set its height/width to fill the entire content area.